# How to retain the username in the textbox in JSP using Spring Java

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP page with 2 textboxes--one for username and another for password. I'm able to get the values entered in both the fields, but I want to retain the username if the password is incorrect. I need to do it with Java using Spring.

My JSP looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right">
    <b>User ID:</b>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="<% if(uname!=null){out.println(uname);}%>" size="15" /><br/>
    <font color="red"><form:errors path="uname" cssClass="validationError"/></font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
  <td align="right">
    <b>Password:</b>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
    <input type=password id="pwd" name="pwd" value="" size="15" /><br/>
    <font color="red"><form:errors path="pwd" cssClass="validationError"/></font>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
  <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="Submit" size="15" />
  <td align="left">
    <input type=reset id="clr" name="clr"value="Reset"onclick="doClear();"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Take the value from the request and put the value in the username input

Comment: @PbxMan I did that. But the value gets appended with the previous value. say, i've entered uname as lakshmi  and pwd as 123. If its wrong,the name gets retained but the next time also if i give a wrong pwd retained name again gets appeneded with the uname value and displays lakshmi,lakshmi.. how to solve this

Comment: I think you can use formbacking object of spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="${uname}" size="15" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="${param.uname}" size="15" />
```

Comment: It works after putting it in this tag value=<core:out value="${param.uname}"/> when I was using it directly then it has been displaying as it is `${param.uname}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Spring tags for creating the form like :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form commandName="book" name="fm" method="post" action="<%=url%>">
    <table cellpadding="4">

        <td>Book Title</td>
            <td><form:input path="bookTitle" size="30" maxlength="80" /></td><span id="infotext">*</span><br />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><form:errors path="bookTitle" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Author</td>
            <td><form:input path="author" size="30" maxlength="80"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><form:errors path="author" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="_finish" value="Save" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Back" onclick="javascript:history.back()"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="<%=listURL.toString() %>">Show all Books</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

> **i think this will help you**